# how to connect an app to a database with python?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I'm new to python, so I want to know how to store the data in a database!

For a sample example, I want to store informations about users :

```
ent1 = input('Enter your name: ')
ent2 = input('Enter your adress: ')
ent3 = int(input('Enter your number phone: '))
```

The question is how to connect the input with the database?

we can take the example of the sqlite3 that is preinstalled in python! and we suppose that we have a database called user.db connected to the cursur and a table called users that contains three columns (name, adress, number_phone)

thanks for the help!

Comment: You have to learn `SQL` - something similar to `cursor.execute('INSERT .... ?, ?, ?', ent1, ent2, ent3)`

Comment: I know SQL! my question is how to store directly the input in the database! because we supposed that I have already created a table! thanks for any clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sqllite3` library to perform SQL `insert` query to insert data into database. For example

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('user.db')

## Create table. Skip if table already exists
conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users
       (name    TEXT NOT NULL,
       adress   TEXT,
       number_phone TEXT);''')

ent1 = input('Enter your name: ')
ent2 = input('Enter your adress: ')
ent3 = int(input('Enter your number phone: '))

#Insert into users table
conn.execute("INSERT INTO users (name,adress,number_phone) \
      VALUES (?,?,?)",[ent1,ent2,ent3]);
conn.commit() #don't forget commit to save data
conn.close()
```

You can also have a look at the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) for detailed info and API references.

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate a database with Python objects.

Create a `dict,` and store all your data therein.

Then, serialise ([`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)) the data to disk (with `pickle.dump`) and next time you need to access/manipulate the data, use `pickle.load.`